# how to show git diff result with visual studio code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

i know how to read git diff result of current file and master with button

[image]

but if i want to show git diff result of different hash commit in visual studio code

Comment: I do not believe VS Code default git integration supports what you want. You'll need to go look for extensions like `GitLens` which increase VS Code git functionality (`Git Graph` and `Git History` are two other extensions that seem like they could work)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) which provides:

- [annotation hover](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens#annotation-hovers)
  [image]
- [file History view](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens#file-history-view)
  [image]

The free features also add extra information in the regular "Source Control" sidebar, more specifically:

- a way to access the list of past commits (with the ["Commits"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens#commits-view) and ["Branches"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens#branches-view) views),
- a button to compare the selected commit with HEAD or with worktree.

[image: https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens/raw/HEAD/images/docs/views-layout-scm.png]

Comment: Just to be known that some of GitLens functionality are behind a paid licence, depending on your work environment https://www.gitkraken.com/gitlens/plus-features?utm_source=gitlens-extension&utm_medium=in-app-links&utm_campaign=gitlens-plus-links

Comment: @Irwene True, but not those, relevant for the OP.

Comment: @LeGEC Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.